# RecyclerView displaying no data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to set data to a RecyclerView.

**Here is the response data.**

```
[
    {
 "shopName": "Hello World.",
 "shopTeluguName": "మమ్మీ",
 "shopAddress": "Bomanahalli"
}, 
    {
 "shopName": "Hello World.",
 "shopTeluguName": "మమ్మీ",
 "shopAddress": "Bomanahalli"
}, 
    {
 "shopName": "Hello World.",
 "shopTeluguName": "మమ్మీ",
 "shopAddress": "Bomanahalli"
}, 
    {
 "shopName": "Hello.",
 "shopTeluguName": "మమ్మీ",
 "shopAddress": "Bomanahalli"
}
]
```

Its parsing and getting it in Arraylist all are working fine but the recycler view is not showing any data. Empty Screen.

**Here is the Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WebServiceInterface {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    RecyclerView recyclerViewShops;
    private int FETCH_SHOPS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    ArrayList<Shop> arrayListShops;
    ShopsAdapter adapterShops;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();

        fetchShops();
    }

    private void init() {

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Shops List");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        recyclerViewShops = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerViewShops.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewShops.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerViewShops.setHasFixedSize(true);

        arrayListShops = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    private void fetchShops() {

        HashMap<String, String> paramsList = new HashMap<>();

        WebServiceController webServiceController = new WebServiceController(
                this, this);
        String hitURL = LinksAndKeys.SHOPS_URL;
        webServiceController.sendGETRequest("", "Loading..", hitURL, paramsList, FETCH_SHOPS_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    public void getResponse(int responseCode, String responseString, String requestType, int requestCode) {
        if (requestCode == FETCH_SHOPS_REQUEST_CODE && responseCode == 200) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Shop[] shops = gson.fromJson(responseString, Shop[].class);
            arrayListShops = new ArrayList<Shop>(Arrays.asList(shops));

            adapterShops = new ShopsAdapter(this, arrayListShops);
            recyclerViewShops.setAdapter(adapterShops);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the Adapter:**

```
public class ShopsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Activity activity;
    private List<Shop> shopList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout linearLayoutParent;
        public TextView textViewShopName, textViewShopTeluguName, textViewShopAddress;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            linearLayoutParent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutParent);
            textViewShopName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopName);
            textViewShopTeluguName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopTeluguName);
            textViewShopAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopAddress);
        }
    }


    public ShopsAdapter(Activity activity, List<Shop> shopList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.shopList = shopList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_shop, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Shop shop = shopList.get(position);

        holder.textViewShopName.setText(shop.getShopName());
        holder.textViewShopTeluguName.setText(shop.getShopTeluguName());
        holder.textViewShopAddress.setText(shop.getShopAddress());

        holder.linearLayoutParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, shop.getShopName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return shopList.size();
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.saravanaeggdistributors.activities.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The response is Fine, ArrayList has the data but recyclerview doesnt show.
Any idea whats wrong here.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `arrayListShops = new ArrayList<Shop>(Arrays.asList(shops));` new memory location will be allocated and the address will be assigned in `arrayListShops` but your `adapterShops` is connected with the old memory location. For this reason when you call `adapterShops.notifyDataSetChanged()` it will check the old memory location and will refresh the list. But you have added the data in newly allocated memory location, so the data is not displaying. You have to add data in old memory location instead of allocating new memory. Update your `getResponse` method as below

```
@Override
public void getResponse(int responseCode, String responseString, String requestType, int requestCode) {
    if (requestCode == FETCH_SHOPS_REQUEST_CODE && responseCode == 200) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Shop[] shops = gson.fromJson(responseString, Shop[].class);
        ArrayList<Shop> tmp = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(shops));
        arrayListShops.addAll(tmp);
        Toast.makeText(this, arrayListShops.size() + " Shops", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        adapterShops.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have checked. The data is there. Even inside the adapter data is proper. Just when the debugger goes to the settext method in OnBindViewHolder in adapter for the second time, it disappears.

Comment: Can you share the project so that I can debug and test it.

Comment: Here it is. I hope it doesnt run properly on your side.!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cyr67cvmlwkj31q/Saravana.zip?dl=0

Comment: It runs. See the update answer above. It shows the shop list.

Answer (score 0):

Common mistake.  You need to set the adapter in your `init()` function with the empty list first.  Then in `fetchShops()` method add the data to the list and call `adapterShops.notifyDataSetChanged()` after to update the view.

Comment: That I tried. Its not working that way as well. The problem is happening somewhere inside the adapter while setText function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything in your code that prevents your `RecyclerView` and its items to show up. Moreover, you use it in a wrong way making new instances of `ShopsAdapter` each time `getResponse` callback is invoked. Just keep the one of the `init` method and only handle `arrayListShops` list adding and removing elements. After doing that, don't forget to call `adapterShops.notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

I think your main problem comes from your layouts. You should see your Shop items following this layouts:

***values/styles.xml***

```
<resources>
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

***layout/activity_main.xml***

In your case better use `RelativeLayout`. You used `LinearLayout` but you missed the important `android:orientation="vertical"` property which for sure wouldn't show your items on screen in your example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  <include
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      layout="@layout/toolbar" />

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***layout/row_shop.xml***

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewShopName"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewShopTeluguName"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewShopAddress"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      />


</LinearLayout>
```